# Comparison operator use in Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am having some trouble with the syntax when I am trying to use the below query in SQL Server. I wanted to show `WHERE` clause based on condition.

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @isActual = 0

SELECT
    SolverRunId, PointId, TimeStampUtc, Value,
    UnitOfMeasure, Reliability
FROM
    (SELECT 
         bt.SolverRunId, bt.PointId, bt.TimeStampUtc,
         bt.Value, bt.UnitOfMeasure, bt.Reliability
     FROM 
         cte bt
     WHERE 
         bt.TimeStampUtc = bt.TargetTimeUtc

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         a.SolverRunId, a.PointId, a.TimeStampUtc, a.Value,
         a.UnitOfMeasure, a.Reliability
     FROM 
         cte a
     WHERE 
         -- I tried using this case but it is syntactically incorrect
         CASE 
             WHEN @isActual = 0 THEN a.TimeStamUtc > @endDateUtc 
             ELSE a.TimestampUtc <= @endDateUtc 
         END
         -- instead of this. I wanted to have conditional where based on @isActual value from 0 to 1
         a.TimeStampUtc > @endDateUtc
         AND a.SolverRunId = @maxRun) x
ORDER BY 
    SolverRunId, PointId, TimeStampUtc;
```

I wanted to have the where condition to be evaluated based on `@isActual` set to true or false

Comment: 1) It's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: 2) It's better to use regular AND/OR constructions instead of case in the WHERE clause.

Comment: `CASE` returns a *scalar* value, not a boolean result. Though don't use a `CASE` **expression** in the `WHERE` anyway, stick to `AND` and `OR` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, don't use a `CASE` in the `WHERE` just use proper boolean logic with `AND` and `OR` clauses. In your question your variable `@isActual` is also missing a data type, so I have *assumed* it is a `bit`:

```sql
DECLARE @isActual bit = 0;
SELECT SolverRunId,
       PointId,
       TimeStampUtc,
       Value,
       UnitOfMeasure,
       Reliability
FROM (SELECT bt.SolverRunId,
             bt.PointId,
             bt.TimeStampUtc,
             bt.Value,
             bt.UnitOfMeasure,
             bt.Reliability
      FROM cte bt
      WHERE bt.TimeStampUtc = bt.TargetTimeUtc
      UNION ALL
      SELECT a.SolverRunId,
             a.PointId,
             a.TimeStampUtc,
             a.Value,
             a.UnitOfMeasure,
             a.Reliability
      FROM cte a
      WHERE a.TimeStampUtc > @endDateUtc
        AND a.SolverRunId = @maxRun
        AND ((@isActual = 0 AND a.TimeStamUtc > @endDateUtc)
          OR (@isActual = 1 AND a.TimestampUtc <= @endDateUtc))) x
ORDER BY SolverRunId,
         PointId,
         TimeStampUtc;
```

You may also want experiment with adding `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause of the above, as the query plan requirements for when `@isActual` has a value of `1` or `0` could be quite different.

Comment: A very good reference for the relative merits of IF, UNION, AND/OR, OPTION RECOMPILE, etc : https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Thank you.. I made a mistake of using Case, when it should easily be done by And OR operator. I seriously made a silly mistake here